# Shared resources in packages made by Electron

Tags: usb, shared, electron

I need to distribute a webapp in an offline version on an USB. Electron seems like a great way to make the webapp feel native and work well on all platforms. There is (potentially) just one problem: The offline version requires several huge media files and therefore there is not enough space for each package to have its own folder with the media files. This can be solved by letting the packages share a common directory on the USB. Can you tell me if this is possible with Electron. And if so, how?

(Note that each package must be available on the USB.)

Comment: I'd love to help you with this problem as it's something I've had to do at my previous job. That said, it's not clear to me what the problem is. Do you have one application accessing many large media files? Or multiple applications accessing them?

Comment: @SteveKinney Currently it is one application (webapp) that accesses many large media files. I want to make that application into three "native" applications (Windows, Mac and Linux) using Electron. The three applications will all need to access the same large media files as the current application. Hope this makes it more clear.